# order by average - Django

Tags: python, django

**I am trying calculate the score average of "Pelicula". the Puntuacion Table is formed by "pelis(foreign key of Pelicula) " , "User(foreign key of Pelicula)" and valor(this is the score)
 this is models.py**

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    fechaNacimiento = models.DateField()
    categorias = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.usuario

class Pelicula(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    anyo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    actores = models.ManyToManyField('Actor')
    resumen = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    puntuacionMed = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    director = models.ForeignKey('Director');
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo

class Actor(models.Model):
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    biografia = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Nombre

class Director(models.Model):
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    biografia = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Nombre

class Puntuacion (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('Usuario')
    pelis = models.ForeignKey('Pelicula')
    valor = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you the answer:

```
from django.db import Avg

Punctuation.objects.values('pelis_id').annotate(average=Avg('valor'))
```